# Using wfs-t in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, wfs-t

I'm using **[OpenLayers-3.6.0](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/)** in a web application. I have wfs layer as follow:

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&" + 
      "service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=usa:states";
var format = new ol.format.WFS({});
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
    format: format
});
layer wfs = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'states',
    source: source
});
```

I edit this Point layer as follow:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Point'
});
```

Now I want to save this layer in server side. In [OpenLayers-2](http://openlayers.org/two/) we defined a saveStrategy and then call save method of it. It is shown as follows:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

/*
* change layer's features
*/

saveStratefy.save();
```

**How can I do it in** [OpenLayers-3.6.0](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at my blog for a bit on WFS-T. This uses the OL 3.5 library.

https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58

Comment: Please include here at least a summary of the contents of the blog post of yours that you are proposing as a link-only answer here.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own blog must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the author of the blog post that I am recommending here".

Answer (score 1):

I don't need it everyday so I didn't reuse it recently but you can look at https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client

It's the place where the code for OpenLayers 3 templates in OpenGeo Suite is. One of these templates is for using WFS-T. You have to look at `ol3edit` and also `ol3-common`. You will need to analyse JavaScript code as they (Boundless, the company behind) made a custom component for this purpose.

Comment: The link is now 404. Is it possible someone with the knowledge of where it pointed to could update it?