# How to upload a shapefile using WFS service?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wfs

I'm trying to make an application that let the user upload his shapefiles and manage him (show/hide, delete, edit, etc...)  I read in the GeoServer documentation that a WFS is the service that can help me to accomplish my purpose.

I searched enough to find an example on how to upload shapefile using this service but I found nothing so I'll be glad I someone help me out.

Comment: You might be better off not doing (at least the initial upload) that way, but just using the REST API: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert it to GML and POST it at the WFS-T endpoint.

Check out this implementation in Leaflet: https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST

This is assuming you're using JavaScript? Basically, I'd use a library, either native Open Layers or that Leaflet plugin linked above.

If you really want to implement it yourself, check out the [WFS standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

Since you're using OpenLayers, you can use the built in WFS-T functions.

See here: https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58 (linked from [this other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155394/using-wfs-t-in-openlayers-3)).

Here's the [OpenLayers example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html) and this is the [OL Documentation for WFS Transation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WFS.html#writeTransaction).

Comment: actually I'm currently using OpenLayer so if there is an example on how to do it with OpenLayer I'll be glad if you help me out with it

Comment: I'll edit my answer, @RamiZK